# Javascript : Undefined before an array

Tags: javascript

i'm having trouble with a little code i'm writing in javascript which is supposed to return a table with a column for month and a column for profits. Everything is okay except it seems that i got a undefined value out of nowhere. Here's the code :

```
"use strict";

var i, mois, ventes, a, b;
mois=["Janvier","Fevrier","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet","Aout","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Decembre"];
ventes=[120,500,350,400,600,890,450,100,250,300,650,450];

function Fventes(a, b) {
    for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
    document.write('<tr><td>', a[i],'</td><td>',b[i],'</td></tr>');
    }
}
document.write('<table><thead><td>Tableau des ventes</td></thead><tbody>');
document.write(Fventes(mois, ventes));
document.write('</tbody></table>');
```

The undefined value appears before the 1st document write, as if i was calling the value of an empty variable.

Comment: Try to avoid `document.write` and consider using _DOM Methods_ instead; i.e. `parent_node.appendChild(table_root_node)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're `document.writing` a function, which returns `undefined` implicitly due to the rules of Javascript. Inside of that function are the `document.writes` you really wanted. Try:

```
"use strict";

var i, mois, ventes, a, b;
mois=["Janvier","Fevrier","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet","Aout","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Decembre"];
ventes=[120,500,350,400,600,890,450,100,250,300,650,450];

function Fventes(a, b) {
    for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
        document.write('<tr><td>', a[i],'</td><td>',b[i],'</td></tr>');
    }
}
document.write('<table><thead><td>Tableau des ventes</td></thead><tbody>');
Fventes(mois, ventes);
document.write('</tbody></table>');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zsh18999/

Answer (score 1):

you should write:

```
document.write('<table><thead><td>Tableau des ventes</td></thead><tbody>');
Fventes(mois, ventes);
document.write('</tbody></table>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `document.write(Fventes(mois, ventes));` actually writes `"undefined"` because calling `Fventes(mois, ventes)` return `undefined`. you should write:

```
"use strict";

var i, mois, ventes, a, b;
mois=["Janvier","Fevrier","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet","Aout","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Decembre"];
ventes=[120,500,350,400,600,890,450,100,250,300,650,450];

function Fventes(a, b) {
    for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
    document.write('<tr><td>', a[i],'</td><td>',b[i],'</td></tr>');
    }
}
document.write('<table><thead><td>Tableau des ventes</td></thead><tbody>');
Fventes(mois, ventes);
document.write('</tbody></table>');
```